# CDVPlugin Error Using Appgyver Steroids and MapKit

Tags: ios, mobile, cordova-plugins

I've been trying to get the MapKit plugin to work for my simple Appgyver Steroids project, but I keep getting the same error no matter what I try:

```
ERROR: Plugin 'MapKit' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

I have the Mapkit plugin added to my project, using the following command:

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.mapkit
```

If I list my cordova plugins I get all of my installed plugins...

```
com.phonegap.plugins.mapkit 0.9.2 "MapKit"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.9 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.9 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.10 "Vibration"
```

I think the problem is in my config.xml, but I'm not really sure how to map the plugins correctly. This is how my config.xml looks at the moment:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.appgyver.helloSteroids" version="3.1.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>
        A fresh new Steroids application.
    </description>
    <author email="contact@appgyver.com" href="http://www.appgyver.com/steroids">
        AppGyver Steroids Team
    </author>

    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="MapKit">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>

    <access origin="*" />

</widget>
```

I'm not really sure what to do here and could really use the help!

Comment: fwiw, from a non-steroids user, you're prolly on the right track. try <feature name="MapKit">
        <param name="ios-package" value="MapKit" />
</feature>

Comment: didn't edit previous answer in time ... try value="MapKitView"

Comment: I changed it and got the same error :( It seems almost like Steroids doesn't recognize the plugin...

Comment: try setting this feature in www/config.ios.xml

Comment: It's still not working, I get the same error. It's so strange! Do you think I should contact support?

Comment: I noticed a typo in the OP CLI instructions. may want to try cordova plugin add https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit.git ... you had 'plugins' ... contacting support is always a good idea ;-)

Comment: That was a typo of the post but not the usage. The plugin was added as you wrote it. I'll send an email to appgyver support. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since you posted this and I imagine you have figured it out by now. I'll talk about the new plugin system anyway because the platform has been updated and plugins are included in a different way now.

When you deploy your Appgyver application to the cloud, and visit the `Configuration` page for iOS or Android there is a plugins section. Instead of using the `.xml` file as it was before, you can now just include a GitHub repository like so:

```
[
    {"source":"https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit.git"}
]
```

That GitHub URL would be from wherever you grab the MapKit plugin.

You then build a debug version of your application (I build a debug scanner version) so you can test that plugin with your current code that uses it. Here is a link for [Build Settings](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/build-settings/build-settings-for-ios/) for iOS that helped me with the process.

With iOS and the scanner application, I was able to open Safari and debug the application. Using the console I could check to see if in fact the plugin was installed by typing `typeof MapKit` or `typeof window.plugins.MapKit` or however the plugin object should be accessed for your plugin. A lot of plugins add themselves to `window.plugins` so that object contains most of what you need to know about what actually got installed.

This is a change from a year ago and the platform has moved forward a lot. Hopefully this finds you well.